# My react app does not seen in github pages like a code

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I watched lots of videos, and I read lots of documentations, but I couldn't do this subject. Can you help me?

First of all, I have an react app on github, HERE:https://github.com/alper-efe-sahin/portfolio-v2
(It completed app)

I have 2 branch, first MASTER branch, and second GH-PAGES branch.

I created GH-PAGES using codes which are npm run build and npm run deploy.
Also you can see my some package json codes here:

```
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  "homepage": "https://github.com/alper-efe-sahin/portfolio-v2",
```

When I try to create github page, it shows my github page, note It's codes. (for instance, it shows react documents, not react codes, not html css etc.)

How can I show my codes like a good website ?

Comment: The GitHub Pages site corresponding to that repo is https://alper-efe-sahin.github.io/portfolio-v2, so the homepage setting is clearly wrong for one thing.

Comment: look again @jonrsharpe it's empty, because my html file empty. I do not use html, I use react, I have different jsx files

Comment: React apps still use HTML... Did you try looking in the console to see why it's a blank page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong value set at the property `homepage` in `package.json`

it should be `https://alper-efe-sahin.github.io/portfolio-v2`

Also add the script `"predeploy": "npm run build"` alongside with deploy in `scripts` so when you run `npm run deploy` it also builds your app with npm first.

source: [The guide I followed for my cra](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f)

Comment: dude, i have my own domain. When I click my own domain ( aesahin.software ) it gives empty page, but github link works. Why?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
it is console log

Comment: have you tried `aesahin.software/portfolio-v2`? I have never tried custom domains so i don't really know how to help you, sorry

Comment: okay thanks. (btw i tried and it does not work)